# Prettier warns me about a trailing comma but after I remove it, it adds it back when I save the save

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier

Prettier warns me that I need to remove trailing commas, then after I remove it the error goes away but Prettier adds that commas again by itself immediately I save. Please help, it seems like a conflict between Prettier and ESLint:

.eslintrc

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "rules": {}
}
```

.prettierrc

```
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "printWidth": 80
}
```

Comment: Do you have prettier configurations set up for ESLint? It is possible for your ESLint rules to not be aligned with your prettier settings (and not necessarily that prettier is the one complaining).

Answer (score 1):

If you want prettier not to add trailing commas, change your .prettierrc to `"trailingComma": "none"` - if you want eslint to not warn you about trailing commas, add `"comma-dangle": "off"` to the rules object in your eslintrc

Comment: I want Prettier to add trailing commas

Comment: Ok, so I imagine its actually eslint that is telling you to remove the trailing comma? In that case, you should add "comma-dangle": "off" to the "rules" object in your eslintrc

Comment: Still the same outcome. VSCode calls it a prettier problem though

Comment: are these rc files in the root of your project? If so, I would imagine that the issue is coming from the prettier plugins to eslint in your extends array, and that those are overriding the comma rule

Comment: The rc files are in the root directory. How do I work around this if it's a plugin issue?

Comment: Here are the comma dangle options for eslint - https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle#comma-dangle - and here are methods to override rules in a config file - https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#extending-configuration-files